# How to call a dynamic function between components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to angular and I'm planning on making a dynamic function on my app. I wanted a dynamic function (ex. Parent component is called, the buttonclick function on the child component will do a console.log , while when parent2 component is called, the buttonclick function will do an alert dialog). Is it possible to  call a dynamic function with different implementations for each component? How will I do it?

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template : '<button click()="dynamicFunction()">Click!</button>',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  dynamicFunction(){
     //do nothing
  }  

  ngOnInit() {  

  }

}
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template : '<app-child></app-child>',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  dynamicFunction(){
      console.log('parent 1 clicked');
  }  

  ngOnInit() {  

  }

}
```

**parent2.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent2',
  template : '<app-child></app-child>',
  styleUrls: ['./parentTwo.component.css']
})
export class ParentTwoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  dynamicFunction(){
      alert('parent 2 was called');
  }  

  ngOnInit() {  

  }

}
```

Comment: Did you perhaps forget some text?  I don't see any question to answer, only code.

Comment: @AlexanderNied sorry. Added question

Comment: I'm a bit confused-- are child one and child two actually supposed to be separate and declared _components_, or are they simply _instances_ of the `EmployeesComponent`?  The way you have your selectors set up (`<app-parent>`, `<app-child>`, `<app-child2>`) but are using the same component class name (`EmployeesComponent`) for all three makes me feel like you might have some deeper misunderstanding about how Angular works at a fundamental level...  Forgive me if I am wrong and simply not understanding the question...

Comment: @AlexanderNied , sorry, I just copy pasted that, forgot to change that.
I thought renaming the ts files will be easier to be understood. *edited code*

Comment: To be honest, I still don't really understand the true issue here-- it is possible a service could be useful, as per @Aniruddha-Das 's answer below.  My hunch is this is maybe better suited for an abstract base class with a static property it iterates and assigns out as these components extend it, but I'm basing that only on what I think the real nature of your question is.  Sorry, I don't think I can be more helpful without really understanding the problem more clearly.

Comment: Just put it inside service, then inject that service in these components

Comment: maybe the question and code are not clear. I'll edit it out.

Comment: edited the question @AlexanderNied, maybe you can help out

Answer (score 2):

**Function shared in angular using service**

In angular you can create service and share that service as provider in all the function. The methods/function in the service can be called from any component including child or non child

Comment: Could you provide an example with OPs code? So that new Angular users can get advice from this link?

Comment: this wont solve it. as I understand the answer, this will only call a global function within two components? Am I right? @Anniruddha Das

Comment: @rjmcb services can be shared across all components. if you declare in module it will be singleton as well. you can also use root to declare it root level

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have created a custom filter service that can be use from components.

filter.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    @Pipe({
      name: 'filter'
    })
    export class CustomFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(items: any, filter: any, defaultFilter: boolean): any {
        debugger;
        if (!filter) {
          return items;
        }
    
        if (!Array.isArray(items)) {
          return items;
        }
    
        if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
          let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);
    
          if (defaultFilter) {
            return items.filter(item =>
              filterKeys.reduce((x, keyName) =>
                (x && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] == "", true));
          }
          else {
            return items.filter(item => {
              return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
                return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || filter[keyName] == "";
              });
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

book-location-name.component.html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered bordered table-striped table-condensed table-text table-scroll table-hover">
          <thead class="thead">
            <tr>
              <th style="width:5%;">Sl</th>
              <th style="width:30%;">Location Name &nbsp;</th>
              <th style="width:25%;">Location Code &nbsp;</th>
              <th style="width:15%;">Is Active &nbsp;</th>
              <th style="width:25%;">Action&nbsp;</th>
              <th *ngIf="LocationNameList.length>5" style=" width: 2%;"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let dataModel of LocationNameList| filter : {LocationName: searchText, LocationCode:searchText} | paginate: config; let i=index">
              <td style="display:none">{{dataModel.BlnId}}</td>
              <td style="width:5%;"> {{i+1}}</td>
              <td style="width:30%;"> {{dataModel.LocationName}}</td>
              <td style="width:25%;"> {{dataModel.LocationCode}}</td>
              <td style="width:15%;">
                <span class="badge" [ngClass]="{'badge-success':dataModel.IsActive, 'badge-secondary':!dataModel.IsActive}">{{dataModel.IsActive==true?'Active':'Inactive'}}</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <i (click)="editData(dataModel)" class="cui-note icons font-2xl mt-4" style="cursor:pointer;"></i>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <i (click)="showConfirmationModal(2,dataModel.BlnId)" class="cui-trash icons font-2xl mt-4" style="cursor:pointer;"></i>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Then in app.module.ts add `import { CustomFilterPipe } from '../filter.pipe'`.

And call it from your components like `book-location-name.component.ts` file.